# How to find all unique paths of a graph from a source point to a destination

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I want to try to find all unique possible paths in a graph from a source to destination node.  For context, I have turn a 2D array into a graph (an adjacency list) and now I want to find all unique paths in that adjacency list. I have tried DFS so far, but I feel that it may not be comprehensive.

Unique is such that a path from source to destination does not share a a vertex or node with another path that is also source to destination.

Comment: There is no known efficient way to do this - there can be exponentially many different paths to pick from. Would you still be interested in an algorithm that (slowly) lists all paths, or are you looking for something else (e.g. number of paths, longest path, shortest path, etc.)?

Comment: I am curious on why there may be no known efficient way to do this?

Comment: There can be exponentially many different paths from one point to another in a graph, so simply listing them all out can take exponential time. There are strategies that are "efficient" in the sense that each path is output relatively quickly after the previous one, but they still take a very long time to run to completion.

Comment: What "strategies" might those be?